# Find element in the table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table

```
 {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.002, 0.08942, -0.08942}, {0.008, 
  0.233889, -0.178706}, {0.018, 0.366918, -0.267724}, {0.031, 
  0.496136, -0.350769}, {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999}, {0.07, 
  0.779356, -0.5245}, {0.095, 0.922931, -0.609077}, {0.124, 
  1.06945, -0.693271}, {0.156, 1.21404, -0.77438}, {0.191, 
  1.35745, -0.852947}, {0.229, 1.50013, -0.929279}, {0.271, 
  1.64566, -1.00987}}
```

and I want to find the right element in the table. For example each row has three columns and I want to specify the value in the first column while the program should return the other two.
Example: If I insert value 0.049 this is element {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999} in the table and I want the computer to return me values 0.639568 and -0.439999.

Can this be done?

Comment: Try `Cases[data,{0.049,a__}]:>a]`

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to extend this "Cases" to this: After he finds the element (in this case {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999}) I want to get out let's say 0.639568 but I don't want to copy that number. Something like [[2]] but I don't know where to put it... ?

Comment: @kale or skrat, maybe you can answer the question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate method, but I rather prefer kale's:

```
FindCol[t_, n_, col_] := t[[Position [t, n][[1, 1]], col]]
FindCol[data, 0.049, 3]

(* -0.439999 *)
```